# How do i get HAML comments to work correctly in Sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Comments should be `-#` not `/` since we don't want this code to be shown to the user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution:

1) Install the textmate bundle
https://github.com/phuibonhoa/handcrafted-haml-textmate-bundle

I think this can be done via the package manager, i just used

`git clone git://github.com/phuibonhoa/handcrafted-haml-textmate-bundle.git Haml.tmbundle`

in the packages folder

2) Delete all files starting with `Ruby Haml` in the `Packages/Rails` folder

3) Restart sublime

Comment: I don't use Rails but I have "Packages/Ruby Haml" folder from previous install. The GIT GUI resulted in several folders such as Commands, Preferences, Snippets... How do I move them in Sublime Text?

Comment: Works great.  You can get to your Packages folder by going to Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Browse Packages.

Comment: Any idea what the solution is for Sublime Text 3 ??

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger, I think that this can solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29655042/977201

Answer (score 2):

You can change your RubyHaml comments preference.

`Preferences > Browse Package > Rails > Ruby Haml Comments.tmPreferences` and edit `TM_COMMENT_START` from `\` to `-#`

Unfortunately this is limited to scope to `<string>text.haml</string>` and doesn't use haml comment/uncomment consistently.

Comment: This should be best answer.