# Sublime Text - How to get haml comments to work correctly on embedded ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2 and a file with "Ruby Haml" syntax, adding Haml comments using the keybinding work fine for haml lines.  However, for an embedded ruby line (a line that starts with `-` or `=`), the comments don't work correctly.  If the cursor is on either end, it's fine.  But if the cursor is in the middle of the line, Sublime adds a ruby comment (`#`).

I tried the package listed in this answer: [How do i get HAML comments to work correctly in Sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267389/how-do-i-get-haml-comments-to-work-correctly-in-sublime-text-2), https://github.com/phuibonhoa/handcrafted-haml-textmate-bundle.  It did not fix it for me.

I also saw this thread: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7346, but it's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my fix: I copied "Ruby Haml Comments.tmPreferences", found in *Packages/Rails*.  I renamed the file "Ruby Haml Embedded Comments.tmPreferences"  I then edited the scope so that the haml comments will work for embedded ruby.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.ruby.embedded.haml</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>/ </string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You can change `/` to `-#` if you prefer that syntax.

**Update**
Sublime Text 3: packages are 7zipped and renamed *PackageName.sublime-package*.  You can find the installed packages in your `Installed Packages` directory (up one level from your `Packages` folder).  Find the *Haml.sublime-package* archive, open with 7zip or similar and you will see the *Comments.tmPreferences* file in the Preferences folder.

However, you don't need to re package plugins in order to use them.  Simply add them to your `Packages` folder like you would for ST2 (`Packages/User` for config files).

Go here for more info on packages: http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#plugins

Comment: It won't work in Sublime Text 3 as the file `Ruby Haml Comments.tmPreferences` is nowhere to be found. Got the feeling this is now in the default Sublime package which prevents us from being able to customize it...

Comment: Thought it would do. But there is no Rails package. I have the feeling it is installed by default in Sublime 3 hence is not in the installed packages folder... I can find `Ruby Haml Comments.tmPreferences.cache` in the `cache` folder, but I have the feeling this is not the right place to look at ...

Comment: Found it in `/opt/sublime_text/Packages/Rails.sublime-package`. Though  I'm still unclear about how to extract the archive, update the file and repack it with the same encoding ...

Comment: You don't need to repack it.  Just put in `Packages/User` folder like ST2.

Comment: Arch linux, the Haml ST3 package can be found here: `/home/you/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages`

Comment: Either way, it's in your home folder, not the installation folder.  Don't touch the /opt/sublime_text directory.