# Sublime colorize :javascript block in haml

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, haml, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have sublime 2/3 and the colorize inside a :javascript block doesn't work fine.

The package is this https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Haml

Actually they says that: "Text inside Ruby, ERB, Javascript, Sass, and CSS filters are now properly recognized so you get all the syntax highlighting, snippets, commands, etc." but in sublime it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have "Ruby HAML" set as the syntax? What color scheme are you using?

Comment: yes, I already set "Ruby Haml" as the syntax and the color scheme is Monokai

Comment: Any improvement on this? :(

Comment: Can you post some sample code so we can see?

Comment: Any change on this? Highlighting in HAML :javascript blocks still not working? http://i.imgur.com/P6N3ObC.png

Answer (score 8):

Sublime 3 comes with preinstalled `Rails` package. This package also contains "Ruby Haml" syntax, which does not highlight embedded js etc. If you press `ctrl + alt + p` and type `haml` you will probably see two `Set Syntax: Ruby Haml`, one from `Rails` package, one from `Haml`. You need the latter to be used.

The best solution for me was to install `ApplySyntax` and in it's user settings add the following:

```
    // Put your custom syntax rules here:
    "syntaxes": [
        {
            "syntax": "Haml/Syntaxes/Ruby Haml",
            "extensions": ["haml"],
            "rules": [
                {"file_name": ".*\\.haml$"}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Haml (https://github.com/phuibonhoa/handcrafted-haml-textmate-bundle) (installed with Package Control) works for me.

Though it would be nice to use it as the default somehow...

Comment: Click the language menu in the lower-right corner and select `Open all with current extension as...`, then pick the language pack you want.

Comment: @dentarg, do you know how to make this default?

Comment: Nope, I don't, sorry :(